# Infinite dimensional representations of $\text{SO}(3)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

In the theory of angular momentum, we wish to study the projective representations of the rotation group $\text{SO}(3)$, for which we turn to the representation theory of the double cover $\text{SU}(2)$.  I understand the finite dimensional representation theory of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ where we find either integer or half integer weights depending on the dimension of the representation. However I have not been able to find a satisfying treatment of the infinite dimensional case. Let $\mathcal{H} = L^2(\mathbb{R^3})$. It is well known that the eigenvalues of the angular momentum operators on this Hilbert space will be integer multiples of $\hbar$, not half integers. How can we see this using representation theory?

Edit: I found an answer with the help of the commenters (thank you!). $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ decomposes as an orthogonal direct sum of vector spaces $V_l$, each of which is invariant under the action of the rotation group and thus irreducible under this action. Furthermore, one can show that each of these vector spaces $V_l$ has dimension $2l+1$, where $l$ is an integer. Thus, each of these spaces is odd. Hence, the projective representation of $\text{SO}(3)$ on each $V_l$ will have integer eigenvalues. See Hall - Quantum Theory for Mathematicians for the proof.

Comment: $SO(3)$ is compact so all unitary representations are equivalent to finite dimensional ones... or are you thinking of some limit of large representation or non-unitary irreps?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero What do you mean all unitary representations are equivalent to finite dimensional ones? If the Hilbert space I want to represent $\text{SU}(2)$ on is infinite-dimensional, how can I realize this as a finite dimensional rep.?

Comment: Decompose the Hilbert space in finite dimensional irreps.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem#Decomposition_of_a_unitary_representation

Comment: @ZeroTheHero this doesn't explain why we only see integer eigenvalues. It appears that in the infinite dimensional case we are only looking at ordinary representations of $\text{SO}(3)$ rather than projective ones, but I do not understand why.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.   Maybe you can clarify what you mean by "infinite dimensional case"?  The eigenvalues of the angular momentum operators (I presume you exclude spin) are always integers.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Spin is a just a special case of the representation theory of $\text{SO}(3)$ where we find a projective unitary representation on a finite dimensional Hilbert space. Because it is projective, we represent $\text{SU}(2)$ instead and we find integer and half integer eigenvalues. I am looking for a representation theoretic explanation as to why in the infinite dimensional case we only get integer values. The Hilbert space of square integrable functions is infinite dimensional, so therefore our representation of $\text{SO}(3)$ must be infinite dimensional.

Comment: No.  The Hilbert space is highly reducible, and decomposes into a direct sum of finite-dimensional (in some cases very large) representations.  @ValterMoretti just answered as I was writing my comment.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 4):

Since $SO(3)$ is compact, in view of Peter-Weyl's theorem, every unitary strongly continuous representation of $SO(3)$ in a Hilbert space is a direct sum (not a direct integral) of finite-dimensional irreducible representations which, in turn, are finite dimensional representations of $SU(2)$. So, once you know all finite dimensional of $SU(2)$ representations you know everything.

Comment: You just beat me to it..

Comment: Sorry...It happens :)

Comment: Not a big deal.  Stay well!

Comment: @ValterMoretti I understand this but it still doesn't explain why we only see integer values eigenvalues when representing $\text{SU}(2)$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. However, I have just found an explanation as to why this is that I will post as an update.

Comment: @JacksonBurzynski please do so!

Comment: I do not understand well the problem. Are you asking why $J_k$ constructed out position and momentum operators lead only to integer eigenvalues?

Comment: @ValterMoretti I was looking for a representation theoretic explanation. See my edit for the explanation.

Comment: What is the distinction between "strongly continuous" as you say, and "continuous"?

Comment: There are three relevant topologies dealing with operators in Hilbert spaces (actually seven but the most relevant are the following three tiles) and in particular for a representation $G \ni g \mapsto U_g$ where $G$ is a topological group and every $U_g$ is a bounded operator on a fixed Hilbert space $\cal H$. **Uniform continuity** $||U_g -U_f|| \to 0$ as $g \to f$, **strong continuity** $U_g \psi - U_f \psi \to 0$ as $g\to f$ for every $\psi \in \cal H$,

Comment: and **weak continuity** $\langle \psi| U_g \phi \rangle \to \langle \psi| U_f \phi \rangle $ as $f \to g$ for all $\psi, \phi \in \cal H$. If the representation is made of unitary operators strong and weak continuity are equivalent. If $\cal H$ is finite dimensional all notions are equivalent.

Comment: Continuous is generic. Usually, in representation theory (also on Banach spaces) continuous means strongly continuous. Uniform continuity is too strong for physical applications as it implies that the generators of unitary representations for Lie groups are bounded and defined on the whole Hilbert space, and it is an impossibly strong requirement in applications to quantum theories where the generators are usually unbounded self-adjoint operators.